# Android Studio Lower Sound than Original Soundtrack

Tags: java, android

I simply want to play an audio with mediaPlayer of Android Studio, but the sound which I hear is too lower than original sound track (Genymotion's emulator sound is at max volume)

Any idea?

```
ImageButton img_scream1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton_scare_1);
    img_scream1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mediaControl = MediaPlayer.create(java_sounds_scary.this,R.raw.scream1_sound);
            mediaControl.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

    Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Playing sound...");
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Place your sound in res/raw folder.

Run your app in a mobile and check it. sometimes geny motion doesn't not work properly.

Comment: int maxVolume = 50;
Then to set setVolume to any value in this range (0-49) you do this:

float log1=(float)(Math.log(maxVolume-currVolume)/Math.log(maxVolume));
yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1-log1);
Nice and easy! And DON'T use AudioManager to set volume! It will cause many side effects such as disabling silent mode, which will make your users mad!

Answer (score 1):

`int maxVolume = 50;

`Then to set setVolume to any value in this range (0-49) you do this:

```
float log1=(float)(Math.log(maxVolume-currVolume)/Math.log(maxVolume));
yourMediaPlayer.setVolume(1-log1);
```

Nice and easy! And DON'T use AudioManager to set volume! It will cause many side effects such as disabling silent mode, which will make your users mad!